# Find distribution, calculate expected value and variance of two random variables

Tags: statistics

I am given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, both are independent:

and X distributioN:

-2 -1 3

0.2 0.3 0.5

and Y distribution:

-1 0 2

0.2 0.4 0.4

I have to create distribution and then I have to calculate expected value and variance of $3X - 2Y$, $X^2 + Y^2$, $X \cdot Y$.

I do not understand how to create distribution of $3X - 2Y$, $X^2 + Y^2$ and $X \cdot Y$ accordingly. After creating distribution, I can calculate Expected value and variance, so I think I do not need any special formulas. However, I cannot understand how $3X - 2Y$ and others should be calculated.

Should I take "each $X$" and "each $Y$" and calculate $3X - 2Y$, so there would be 36 items? 
I do not really understand how this works and what is a meaning of $3X - 2Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are two random indpendent variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant $X$ and $Y$ to be independent such that $X$ has probability mass function given by
$$
P(X=k)=
\begin{cases}
0.5 &\quad \text{if }k=3\\
0.3 &\quad \text{if }k=-1\\
0.2 &\quad \text{if }k=-2\\
\end{cases}
$$
and $Y$ has probability mass function
$$
P(Y=k)=
\begin{cases}
0.4 &\quad \text{if }k=2\\
0.4 &\quad \text{if }k=0\\
0.2 &\quad \text{if }k=-1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then using [the law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) we obtain
$$
E[X]=3\cdot 0.5+(-1)\cdot 0.3+(-2)\cdot 0.2=0.8
$$
and similarly $E[Y]=0.6$. By applying the law again, we can also obtain expressions for $E[X^2]$ and $E[Y^2]$. Having them in hand, we can find the variance of $X$ and $Y$ by the formula
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2
$$
and similarly for $Y$.

Now you're able to calculate the mean and variance of $3X-2Y$ by using that
$$
E[3X-2Y]=3E[X]-2E[Y],
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Var}(3X-2Y)=3^2\mathrm{Var}(X)+(-2)^2\mathrm{Var}(Y)
$$
where we explicitly used that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties).

In a similar manner you can compute the mean and variance of $X^2+Y^2$, but to compute the mean and variance of $X\cdot Y$ you need to use that
$$
E[g(X)g(Y)]=E[g(X)]\cdot E[g(Y)]
$$
for any (measurable) function $g$.

Comment: This makes sense... However, there is also a question to "show distribution for 3X-2Y and others" (Is this some function in form P(3X-2Y = k)?

Comment: I mean what makes P(3X-2Y = k)? Every x combination with every y? So total 9 values?

Comment: Yes, to find the distribution of e.g. $3X-2Y$ you simply go through all combinations of $(X,Y)$ values. Then you will have to find the probability of $P(3X-2Y=k)$ for $k=-10,-7,-6,-4,-3,-1,5,9,11$. For example$$P(3X-2Y=11)=P(X=3,\,Y=-1)=P(X=3)\cdot P(Y=-1)=0.1,$$ where we have used the independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I am sorry, I still need help to calculate E[X^2]... ?

Comment: Use the law of the unconscious statistician:$$E[X^2]=3^2\cdot P(X=3)+(-1)^2\cdot P(X=-1)+(-2)^2\cdot P(X=-2)$$